# How to convert " 2016-11-06 21:09:55" to [07, e0,11,06,21,09,55] in swift

Tags: swift, hex

BLE in data transmission, need to put the time into 7 byte, the 2016 converted to hexadecimal other unchanged，how to convert "2016" to [0x07,0xe0]

Answer (score 0):

`2016` becomes `0x7E0` in hexadecimal, so you just need to split higher byte and lower byte. Seems to be a step-1 exercise of the C-language.

```
func getYearBytes(year: Int) -> [UInt8] {
    let yearByte0 = UInt8(year>>8)
    let yearByte1 = UInt8(year & 0xFF)
    return [yearByte0, yearByte1]
}
print(getYearBytes(year: 2016)) //-> [7, 224] (in decimal) ([0x07, 0xE0] in hexadecimal)
```